# Development of Qt app using MSVC source code

Tags: qt

Is there anyway that we an use visual studios source code into Qt source code? to develop a application on image processing.
i had a program on visual studio but i don't understand how to use that code in Qt 5.
can anyone please tell me how can we use it

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

actually, it depends how is your project.

if you previous project is C++ and design good. UI just a present layer, it should not be heavy work.

but if your image processing logic are strong related to MFC, you might spend lots of time on your migration.